determine whether a function is coercive or not
For the next exercise, I need to check whether the next function is coercive, the function is of the form: $$f(x,y)=x^2 -2xy^2+\frac{y^{4}}{4}. $$
So far I tried to square it and bound it from below, I used the identity $(x-y^2)^2 >0$  and polar coordinates.
could I use polar coordinates and said that for a proper angle ,$\theta$, $f(r, \theta)= - \infty$ as $r$ goes to $\infty$
Thanks!

Squaring a function to prove coercive is not a common technique that I see.

\begin{align}f(x,y)&= x^2-2xy^2 + \frac{y^4}4 \\
&=(x-\frac{y^2}2)^2-xy^2\end{align}
Let's travel along $x=\frac{y^2}2$, then $$f\left(\frac{y^2}2, y \right)=0-\frac{y^2}4<0$$ and hence it can't be coercive.

could I use polar coordinates and say that for a proper angle,theta, f(r, theta)= - infinity as r goes to infinity

I don't think so, if you fix a $\theta$, it means that you are traveling along a straight line through eh origin. The values would go to $\infty$. My counterexample is by traveling through a nonlinear path.

Notice that $\lim_{t\to\infty}\|(at^2,t)\|= \infty$, but
$f(at^2,t)=\left(a^2-2a+\frac{1}{4}\right)t^4=0$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$ if
$a=1\pm\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$, hence $f(x,y)$ is not coercive.
